# Backup files as owner using a Live CD?

Tags: permissions, backup, nemo

My partition in Linux Mint 18 is in need of repair, but first I will backup some files using a Live CD. I can't copy the two files that I want, Bookmarks and Bookmarks.bak, because I am not the owner thus don't have permissions. How can I become the owner and obtain permissions?

When I open Nemo, I can access my hard drive from the sidebar. Since I am not owner, I had tried `gksudo nemo`.  When Nemo opened with privileges, The hard drive wasn't listed in the sidebar. The files path is:

`/media/mint/bfcc9b0f-abbf-49cc-86a7-4b97475bf409/home/luis/.config/chromium/Default`

Comment: `sudo bash` should work in a liveCD, from there you can use plain `cp -r` (or `rsync`, or even `scp` given you have connectivity and a network drive to backup things to).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root in the livecd (`sudo` should work) to copy files. If you want to preserve permissions, pass `--preserve=all`; you can also pass `-a` to imply `-dR --preserve=all` (`-d` preserves symbolic links; if you don't know what this means, you probably want to preserve them).

Example:

```
cp -a /media/mint/bfcc9b0f-abbf-49cc-86a7-4b97475bf409/home/luis/.config/chromium/Default /path/to/destination
```

Comment: I did this:                                                                                                                                          sudo su
cp -a /media/mint/bfcc9b0f-abbf-49cc-86a7-4b97475bf409/home/luis/.config/chromium/Default /home/Mint/Desktop

And got this:                                                                                           cp: cannot start /media/mint/bfcc9b0f-abbf-49cc-86a7-4b97475bf409/home/luis/.config/chromium/Default': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I managed to copy the files using a Debian LiveCD. I didn't even need to become root, and I could copy them straight from the graphical desktop environment.